# How to check overlapping dates between multiple date ranges?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Sorry for my bad english, but I have a problem about check duplicate date.

I have a list date includes from_date and to_date in database and I want check like below:

In database:

```
from_date   | end_date 
-------------------------
2020/02/10  | 2020/02/15 
-------------------------
2020/01/20  | 2020/01/31 
-------------------------
2020/02/16  | NULL
-------------------------
```

Input:

```
input['from'] = 2020/01/15;
input['to'] = 2020/01/25;
```

```
input['from'] = 2020/01/10;
input['to'] = NULL;
```

NULL meaning the date unlimited after.

Condition:

Check input[from] and input[to] does not overlap with another range in the database.

in this case:

input is invalid: 
because

dates in 2020/01/15 - 2020/01/25 overlap with range 2020/01/20  - 2020/01/31

dates in 2020/01/10 - NULL overlap with range 2020/02/16 - NULL

valid case:

- 2020/02/01 - 2020/02/09
- 2020/01/10 - 2020/01/19

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following logic to get rows that have any overlap (other than the endpoints) for the parameters:

```
select d.*
from dates d
where d.from_date < @to and
      (d.to_date > @from or d.to_date is null)
```